# How to serve the latest API through application mime - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the following

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
      resources :profiles
    end
    namespace :v2 do
      resources :users
      resources :profiles
    end
  end
```

instead of routing to api/v1 and api/v2, what i would like is set the accept header to use which ever i want it to serve and use the path `api` neglecting the version.

So if i set it to serve api/v1 the path should just be `localhost:3000/api`

i was going through this railcasts video

`http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?autoplay=true`

but looking in comments there are variable issues with the code and the solution at time.

What is the best solution at the moment?

Replies from that link

```
    Each time you create a new MIME type name (application/vnd.example.v1, application/vnd.example.v2, ...),
 a kitten is hurt! don't do that! that's bad!

    Use MIME parameters instead: application/vnd.example; version=1, application/vnd.example; version=2, ... 
(version=, or level=, or v= or whatever you want, this is part of your design).

    The semantic of a MIME type is that every document "flagged" with that type share the same "lineage", 
and that two different names are not related, even if they share a same prefix.

    By incorporating a version identifier into the MIME type name,
 you are making the names distinct and are in the same case as if your V1 API was using text/html documents 
whereas your V2 now uses image/png pictures instead.





The problem with the default is it will accept any mime type, as it will only check the boolean and not the string:

@default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.example.v#{@version}")
I mean, if we're expecting "application/vnd.github.v1", it will also accept "application/vnd.twitter.v1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the approach described in that Railscast in several projects, and haven't had any problems with it. I think it is a really good and up to date solution.

Place this in your /lib directory:

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.yourdomain.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

Then define your routes as follows:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
    resources :users
    resources :profiles
  end
  scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) do
    resources :users
    resources :profiles
  end
end
```

You can now access the API with end points like:

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/api/users
https://www.yourdomain.com/api/profiles
```

Which will serve up version 2 by default.

Or you can set an Accepts header like:

```
Accept: application/vnd.yourdomain.v1
```

and you'll get version 1 instead.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: i've added some responses that the railcasts video got . What are your thoughts on those? thanks

Comment: It would be trivial to modify the matches? method in the ApiConstraints class to look at the a version parameter on the mime.

That's actually a fair comment.... So the accept header would become

Accept: application/vnd.yourdomain; version=1

And likewise, you can make sure the matches? method checks the validity of the "yourdomain" part of the mime.

Comment: Actually, I don't agree with the last comment. It won't match on "application/vnd.twitter.v1" because include? is pattern matching for the entire string application/vnd.yourdomain.v before the version number.

Comment: question. what if my controllers are like this `Api::v1::controller_name` instead of modules?

Comment: In my projects I have:

app/controllers/api/v1/users_contoller.rb

which is defined like:

module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < BaseController
    end
  end
end

So this defines:
Api::V1::users_controller.rb

Comment: hmm i have just implemented this and it works great thank you. But instead i used the `Api::V1::users_controller.rb` structure. Also used the first comment that you agreed on with `...yourdomain; version=#{version}`